# How upgrade magento 2 via composer to alternative version PHP

Tags: php, magento2.2, upgrade, composer

1. Alternate version **php 7.0.24** - my site.
2. Native version **PHP 5.2.6** - my server.

**Composer** doesn't want to update magento (it defined version **PHP 5.2.6**).

**How to specify for the script an alternative version PHP?**

Answer (score 0):

Check the list of available php versions in your server using below command.

> which php

Now, suppose your php version is php70,
then you can run the cli command using your specific php version like this

> php70 bin/magento setup:upgrade

If you want to run composer update command then you have to define your php file path then enter your command
For example:

> /usr/bin/php70 composer update